# Flask url_for for html <tr>

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a websockets app where I show the clients connected. I use flask for the front-end.

When a new client is connected I add it to the `clients` list in python.

HTML side, I have a table who receives the clients list through Jinja, and it creates a row for every client connected. This table is refreshed every 2 seconds with js.

My clients list is a list of dictionaries:

```
clients = [
    { 'cp_id':'Jhon',
      'last_heartbeat_from_now':datetime.utcnow()
    }
    ...
]
```

I have my table like this:

```
<table id="clients">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last time connected </th>
        <th>Health</th>
    </tr>
    {% for i in clients %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i['cp_id'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ i['last_heartbeat_from_now'] }}</td>
        <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='green.png') }}" class="health"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I want to make every row `<tr>` to be clickable and to redirect to a dynamic URL with the name of the person. For example when I click Jhon in the HTML I want to create the dynamic url : localhost:5000/dashboard/Jhon.

I tried using

```
<tr onclick="{{ url_for('dashboard', cp_id = i['cp_id']) }}">
```

But it doesn't do anything.
I tried making a data-href:

```
<tr data-href="{{ url_for('dashboard', cp_id = i['cp_id']) }}">
```

But I'm not sure how to use this.

And finally my python code for the route part is this:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<string:cp_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def dashboard(cp_id):
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

The best way to do this is using `data-href`:

```
<tr data-href="{{ url_for('dashboard', cp_id = i['cp_id']) }}">
```

Your rows are added dynamically so your script needs to delegate events. This means that the onclick event need to come from a static parent (if you can, the closest one from the dynamic children, in this case I use document).

If you don't delegate events from the static parent to the dynamic child, it won't work. Like this for example:

```
jQuery("tr[data-href]").on("click", function () ...
```

**This won't work in you html.**

Delegating event handlers will make the job.

And you add your jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(document).on("click", "tr[data-href]", function() {
            window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('data-href');
         });
    });
</script>
```

And if you want to add the 'hand' effect on hovering the row, just add this to your CSS:

```
[data-href] { cursor: pointer }
```